# Effect of bad weather on P2P Communication or Broadcasting?

Tags: telecommunication

I stop receiving TV signals whenever their is cloud cover outside. On the other hand I have never had any such problems with my internet connection or GPS system. I cannot understand why and how often (or easily) these different technologies get affected by bad weather conditions.

So my question(s) would be:

- How often and why does satellite broadcasting get affected due to weather conditions?
- How often and why does point-to-point (using satellites) get affected?
- How often and why does point-to-point (using line of sight) get affected?

By how often I mean how much worse weather conditions have to be for communication to be affected.

Comment: What is your current setup for TV? Do you use a satellite dish, a line-of-sight dish, cable?

Comment: @wasabi It's satellite dish.